# Carriage return is (sometimes) not working in my spyder ipython console

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, spyder, carriage-return

I am trying to have a little python command-line tool, which updates measurement values and prints it. I wanted to use a simple `print(f'{value}', end='\r')` that writes to the stdout in a loop.

However, somehow this works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't:

This works:

```
def trial():
    idx = 0
    print('Press Ctrl-C to exit.')
    while True:
    idx = idx % 100
         try:
             print(f'This is the actual value of idx: {idx}', end='')
             time.sleep(0.1)
         except KeyboardInterrupt:
             break
         finally:
             print('', end='\r')
             idx += 1
```

The output of trial() is:

```
Press Ctrl-C to exit.
This is the actual value of idx: 21
```

But this version doesn't work:

```
def trial():
    idx = 0
    print('Press Ctrl-C to exit.')
    while True:
        idx = idx % 100
        try:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(f'This is the acutal value of idx: {idx}', end='')
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        finally:
            print('', end='\r')
            idx += 1
```

Here the output is:

```
Press Ctrl-C to exit.
This is the acutal value of idx: 1This is the acutal value of idx: 2This is the acutal value of idx: 3This is the acutal value of idx: 4This is the acutal value of idx: 5This is the acutal value of idx: 6....
```

Does anybody have a clue why this is the case?

I use Spyder v5.2.2 on Windows10 with Python v3.9.1 and Ipython v7.19.0.

Comment: I found out that, if I start the print of a string with a `\r` it will also work.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st case, idx = idx % 100 is actually out of the loop, so the loop never executes. Try indenting within the 'while True' cycle, and getting the message out of the loop:

```
    import time

def trial():
    idx = 0
    print('Press Ctrl-C to exit.')
    print('This is the acutal value of idx ', end='')
    while True:
        idx = idx % 100
        try:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(f'{idx}', end='\r')
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        idx += 1

trial()
```

Comment: Hi @trotex! Your Version gives me `This is the acutal value of idx 0123456789101112131415` which is still not what I pursued.. Anyhow, I found out that it seems to be some kind of race condition. In my version above, I sometimes had the line cleared and sometimes not.. After changing the sleep time to 0.5 s, it worked.